# adding zero in between string

Tags: sql, oracle

I have three scenarios.

**Scenario 1:**

If i have the following string

Actual String: `1111-2222-33`

Need to replace like by adding leading zero.

Formatted String: `01111-2222-33`

**Scenario 2:**

If i have the following string

Actual String: `11111-222-33`

Need to replace like by adding zero before start of first '-'

Formatted String: `11111-0222-33`

**Scenario 3:**

If i have the following string

Actual String: `11111-2222-3`

Need to replace like by adding zero before start of second `'-'`

Formatted String: `11111-2222-03`

How can I convert the above string? Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you done so fare ? SO is not a coding service

Comment: @Temani Afif i didn't get you.

Comment: [so] is not a _free coding_ website. Please show us the effort you've put in and what you've tried so far. We're here to help when you run in to problems but **not** to write your code for you. I'd recommend you take the [tour] and read the [ask] page to learn how to ask a proper question.

Comment: So you want 5 digits with leading zeros in the first segment, 4 digits also left padded with zeros in the second segment, and 2 left padded digits in the third segment?

Comment: @Sentinel. Yes, correct.

Comment: i mean that we are not here to do the work for you ... we are here to help if you have issue with something you already done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this. It uses standard string functions, which may be important if performance is an issue (standard functions are much faster than regular expression functions).

Note, however, that this will also convert the string `'do-it-yourself'` to `'000do-00it-yo'`. If that is not desired, you must explain all your rules in the original post.

```
with
  inputs ( str ) as (
    select '1111-2222-33' from dual union all
    select '11111-222-33' from dual union all
    select '11111-2222-3' from dual union all
    select '1234-03-0'    from dual
  )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE. Use your actual table and column names.
select str, 
       lpad(substr(str, 1, instr(str, '-') - 1), 5, '0') || '-' ||
       lpad(substr(str, instr(str, '-') + 1, 
                        instr(str, '-', 1, 2) - instr(str, '-') - 1), 4, '0')
       || '-' || lpad(substr(str, instr(str, '-', 1, 2) + 1), 2, '0') as new_str
from   inputs
;

STR          NEW_STR     
------------ -------------
1111-2222-33 01111-2222-33
11111-222-33 11111-0222-33
11111-2222-3 11111-2222-03
1234-03-0    01234-0003-00
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of argument, here's another method using regular expressions.  For the first element, select the first occurrence of up to 5 digits that are followed by a dash, then lpad with zeroes to a length of 5.

```
with tbl(str) as (
  select '1111-2222-33' from dual union all
  select '11111-222-33' from dual union all
  select '11111-2222-3' from dual union all
  select '1234-03-0'    from dual
)
select 
  lpad(regexp_substr(str, '(\d{0,5})-', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 5, '0') || '-' ||
  lpad(regexp_substr(str, '(\d{0,4})-', 1, 2, NULL, 1), 4, '0') || '-' ||
  lpad(regexp_substr(str, '-(\d{0,2})$', 1, 1, NULL, 1), 2, '0') formatted 
from tbl;
```